# Looking to build a signal level converter to reduce 20V input to 3.3V out. Am I on the right track?

Tags: voltage-regulator, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm working on a small pet project with my Raspberry Pi and I'm looking to hook it up to some sensors.

The output from the sensors is normally at 0V, but when the sensor is triggered goes up to 20V. Since the Raspberry Pi's GPIO works on 3.3V logic levels, I've been researching how best to drop the input voltage from 20V to 3.3V, so it won't fry my Pi's GPIO ports.

The Pi doesn't need to send anything back, it's strictly one-way into the Pi, and the line will only go to 20V when the sensor is triggered.

In my research, I read about a circuit consisting of an LM317 variable regulator and 2 resistors, which should give me the 20V to 3.3V that I need, however I'm worried about the kind of heat that such a circuit could produce given the 20V-3.3V voltage drop.

Here's a schematic of what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIhTe3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

To add to things, I'm likely to be adding more 20V connections to other IO ports on the Pi (probably up to 15), so I'm also considering what the combined heat could be.

Am I on the right track, and is the heat just something that I'm going to have to work with? Or is there a better solution out there?

Comment: What kind of line. Are these outputs or inputs or both?

Comment: Device outputs 20v into the Pi.  Only one way.

Comment: You need signal logic level converting (20v -> 3.3v few mA), not power converting (hundreds of mA or Amps)

Comment: Yes.  I've re-worded my question to make it a bit clearer...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If they are signals to the Pi then use a resistor [potential divider](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider). A 1 kΩ across the input and 0 V of the Pi and a 9 kΩ resistor from the Pi input to a high voltage logic signal will reduce that voltage by ten to one. You should be looking for slightly less than a 10:1 reduction. Can you work this bit out yourself? See the link.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't this tie Vout directly to Vin?

Comment: @nageeb. Vout would be separated from Vin by the 9k resistor. The 1k connects from pi input to ground thus acting as a ten to one attenuator.

Comment: @nageeb I've added your diagram with the resistors in place. Remember you'll need to calculate a different value for the 9k to get 3V instead of 2V but I'm assuming you are able to think this one through. Let me know if you need help here.

Comment: So I'm looking for a 5K resistor... Seems simple enough. I'll give it a shot. thanks!

Comment: Sounds about right but err on the safe side and choose 5k6. It'll still be ok .

Comment: Is this solution also good choice, if signal is a waveform with  frequency of let's say 10-30kHZ? Will solution introduce any noise on signal. The resistors are not really precision component.

Comment: @MitjaGustin resistors introduce thermal noise and, considering a 100 kHz bandwidth that noise would be about 4 uV RMS. Small enough? You decide. Resistors are very good (or can be on) precision and if necessary 0.1% resistors could be used.

Comment: Oscilloscope shows straight line for square wave signal without voltage divider, and noisy line (very small ripples) for signal coming out of voltage divider. It looks like high frequency noise. I'm using 555 timer.

Comment: @MitjaGustin this question was answered and accepted back in 2013. If you have a related but not identical question then please raise it formally as a new question incorporating the circuit diagram you used and provide a cross-link to this question.

Answer (score 5):

The two solutions posted so far ignore one factor - isolation. It may or may not matter, but I would use an opto-isolator (EG a 4n25) just for peace of mind (and they're dirt cheap).

The LED side can be driven from the 20v signal with an appropriate resistor.

The sensor side just needs a pullup or down (depending how you wire it) to the pin of the Pi. In fact, you *might* get away without a pullup resistor if the Pi's CPU has internal pullups, but I suspect they'd be very weak and it's not good to rely on these things.

This way, if your input signal accidentally becomes 25v, or 50v, or 500v, or -5v, your Pi does not go "bang".

To add an example circuit, substitute 5v for your 3v3 supply. D1 is optional, but it's nice to leave it in to protect against reverse-voltages:

[image]

Comment: I see the use of the OptoIsolator here, but I'm not sure if it's applicable in my case.  How/Where does the 3.3v (5v in this schematic) factor in? I think I might not have been clear enough in my Question, and have re-worded it and included a schematic.

Comment: OK, it works like this: Your 20v goes into the "12v" end and makes the LED light up inside the opto. This makes the transistor in the opto conduct electricity, which pulls the IO pin down to ground. R2 makes sure it goes back up to 3v3 when the LED switches off. R1 limits the current through the LED. D1 means that if some dolt connects things the wrong way round, nothing bad happens. The fact the link is activated by light and there's no direct electrical connection means that, if things go bad from the 20v end, the 4n25 might die but your Pi will live on.

Comment: I like the idea of isolation, it's very comforting. So I understand, this circuit will effectively invert the i/o, at the Pi, so when the input goes hi, at the Pi, it goes low.  And I also have to supply an additional 5v to make this circuit happen, right?

Comment: @nageeb the 5v is just because John reused this schematic from some other post. Just use 3.3v instead. And yes, the input levels are reversed. Otherwise, you can connect the optocoupler's collector to 3.3v directly, and the emitter to ground through the resistor. Then connect the input to the emitter, like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/KTH7Z.png this would be a non-inverting input.

Comment: I like this solution, but it seems a bit overkill for my current requirements. If this project goes to production, I just might need to step the game up to something like this though.  Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 2):

While the optocoupler might be the best choice if you need isolation, other options are available.

A simple **3.3v Zener Diode and current limiting resistor** is another one. Unlike a voltage divider, who's output depends on the ratio between resistors and input voltage (At 20v, a 10:1 divider is 2v out, but if 20v becomes 30v, it's 3v. This can be a problem with voltage spikes), a zener diode should always clamp a higher voltage down.

[image]

R1 should be about 10k or higher. This should limit current to 2mA or less.

Comment: this is what rasp pi websites recommend as far as I can tell. It also seems that limiting the current to below 0.5mA is also a good idea and maybe an output resistor of a few hundred ohms will help too. It seems, from what I can tell that the RP is a fragile little thing but there doesn't appear to be manufacturers specs on it.

Comment: @Andyaka broadcom doesn't like to release specs on their SOCs. Or anything really.

Comment: very odd - and I was thinking of getting one.

Comment: @Andyaka not really. Broadcom only thinks their direct customers, oems, should have access to datasheets, and under NDA. Same reason broadcom routers are poorly if at all supported under dd-wrt or openwrt.

Answer (score 1):

I do this fairly regularly in the products I design.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJY5RN.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For your application, you'll want to use a Schottky diode to guarantee you get the logic low. If you want to be really safe, add a pair of clamping diodes.

Comment: @ThePhoton That is why I said using a Schottky may have a slight advantage. I suggested it because I know it works.

Comment: If you shorted the diode the lowest voltage seen at the input would be 1.65V due to the two 10k resistors halving the 3.3V rail.

Comment: @Andyaka That would be because I drew it wrong, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For converting signal levels from 20V to 3.3V you don't need LM317. The simplest (and very good) schematic for such things is the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSxjTA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This schematic has additional advantage that protects the 3.3V input from external influences, for example high negative or positive voltage peaks, static discharges, etc.

Depending on R1 power rating, the schematic can withstand input signals up to several hundreds volts for short time and several thousands volts static discharge without harm for the low voltage logic.

It works following way:

1. If the input voltage is higher than 3.3V+0.6V = approx 4V, the diode D1 will open and will clamp the voltage in the point 1 to approximately 4V
2. If the input voltage is lower than -0.6V the diode D2 will open and the 
   voltage in point 1 will be clamped to approx -0.6V. If the signal never goes under zero, D2 is always closed and can be safely removed. (But then there will be no protection to negative input signals)
3. This way, the input voltage from 0..20V will be reguced to -0.6 .. +3.9V that is safe for all 3.3V CMOS devices. As long as this voltage is a little bit higher than the CMOS logic power voltage, some small current will flow through the input protection diodes of the CMOS ICs - it is determined by the difference between the forward voltage of the silicon diodes (D1 and D2) and the schottky protection diodes used by CMOS technology and the resistance of R2. This current will be approximately few mA. If this is too big, D1 and D2 can be changed to low current schottky diodes and this way making input current close to zero.

You can read more for the CMOS protection schematics in the following [Fairchild application note](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/an/AN/AN-248.pdf).

**Additional information:** As long as some people think that the above schematic can cause the Raspberry Pi GPIO IO failure, I made some effort and found [GPIO electrical specifications](http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/microcontroller-projects/raspberry-pi/gpio-pin-electrical-specifications#fig1). According to this document, the input protection diodes are not schottky, but silicone. This way, the above schematic will work even with smaller input current than expected.

Additionally, I increased the value of R2 to 10k, in order to increase the reliability of the schematic (in price of the maximal speed).

Anyway, this is the last edit by myself to this answer.

Comment: While good information for stepping down a power source, OP actually needs signal level converting. A Power regulating LDO or Switching Supply would not be a good or cheap solution here.

Comment: @Passerby: Sorry the word LM317 mislead me. It is fixed now.

Comment: The output signal will be +3.9V not 3.3V.

Comment: @Andyaka - yes, of course. That is why R2 is there. (BTW, check the acceptable input voltages for 3.3V logic).

Comment: Maybe you can supply a link that describes this?

Comment: Remember we're talking about a RaPi here not any old CMOS or TTL - I think you might find that your circuit might damage the pi.

Comment: @johnfound Can you explain why the two diodes are reversed?

Comment: @1p2r3k4t - I will edit the answer in attempt to explain how this schematic works. BTW, I am a little bit confused. This schematic is a classic and very widely used. I though, everyone can imagine how it works.

Comment: @johnfound Thank you, I thought you were trying to use them as zeners and got confused. It is very clear now

Comment: I really do think you need to research how sensitive the RaPi is to overvoltage and current. Everything I've seen points to this circuit as potentially harmful to the device.

Comment: @johnfound Attacking users is not acceptable, a technical discussion does not include calling someone ignorant.

Comment: @Kortuk - I am not trying to be rude or to "attack" anyone. I explained the schematic in details and my answer contains not my inventions, but classic solution, described in every decent electronics book. So, if someone thinks this solution is not working, he probably didn't read these books. So, how I should call such a person? Is "illiterate" better?

Comment: My issue, and probably @Andyaka 's issue is that many new chips have stricter absolute maximum voltages than 0.6V + vdd. For example, the msp430 series datasheet lists the maximum voltage on any pin as VDD + 0.3V. Unfortunately ,the electrical specifications for the rpi are not public,  so we're left to guess. What would you call someone who doesn't read the datasheet? ;)

Comment: @W5VO - It is important **why** there is such limit? Because on higher voltages, the input protection schottky diodes of the IC opens and the input current becomes too high. That is why R2 is used in the above schematic. It limits the input current of the IC to acceptable ranges. Also, as I already wrote in the answer, schottky D1 and D2 can be used that will limit the input voltage even more.

Comment: @johnfound While this generic solution is common enough for classic, generic 3.3 Volt CMOS logic, it is unwarranted as a recommendation for a device for which the absolute maximums are not published. Unless you have access to some NDA restricted datasheet for the specific BroadComm SoC, this answer is based on an assumption that could potentially harm the RPi: Such assumptions are not a basis for an engineering answer. -1.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh - read the additional notes in the answer. I just added link to the RPi GPIO electrical specification.

Comment: @johnfound I didn't find the official specification and absmax values at the site you have linked. Perhaps I misread that page, so please quote the (not speculative) absmax rating specification.

Comment: as crazy as it may sound, the double 1n4148 diode protection may cause the 3V3 rail to raise if there isn't enough current sink on the rail from the rest of the circuit. These days, with all the circuits being low power, this scenario becomes possible. 20V over 10k means 2mA going into the rail capacitor, through D1.